# Webdrive errors from Firefox

Tags: firefox, webdriver

A client ran a small test for me, her Firefox fails with errors...and yet it runs on mine.

> First is "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or
>   inaccessible.", which is then followed by "The update could not be
>   installed. Please make sure there are no other copies of Firefox
>   running on your computer, and then restart Firefox to try again." Then
>   a new Firefox window is opened with an empty tab in it (and no
>   navigation bar, unlike all the other Firefox windows I have opened
>   right now).

Is she going to have to add some addons to her browser?

Comment: How do you initialize the Firefox?

Comment: from selenium import webdriver\n
import sys\n
import os\n
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox as Browser\n
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait\n
\n
browser = webdriver.Firefox()\n

As it turns out, she just informed me that her firefox - which was open at the time - had initiated an update as this test was loading...\n
\n
I had another tester run it, and he had no problems, so I'll assume it was the updating browser that was the culprit...\n

Comment: Sorry about the mess in that reply - how do I make this field show separate lines???

Comment: Best way would be updating your question ;)